# Angular Material: Mat-select don't get the value of the form selected when this value is an object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

I have the following code:

```
<mat-select formControlName="x" #xyz>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let x of xList" [value]="x">{{ x.name }}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

The x object is something like this:

```
x: {id: string, name: string}
```

My problem is that i use a service to get all the objects 'x', and then I get the user who owns an attribute equal to object x for edit, but the select value don't get the value of user.x as selected.

In my .ts file is:

```
formUser = this.formBuilder.group({
id: null,
x: {
  id: null,
  name: null
}});
```

And in the constructor:

```
if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state){
  this.user = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.user;
  this.formUser.patchValue(this.user);
}
```

How can solve this?

Comment: You should post a Stackblitz demo with your issue, that should make easier to help you. For you problem, and think you have to bind your mat-select to the selected value.

Comment: Yeah, i have binded several inputs and selects with formControlName, but this, which is the only one that is an object, is giving me problems

Comment: Try [ngValue] instead of [value]

Comment: Don't you need a `compareWith` method on the `<mat-select>` tag ? https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek with ngValue is the same

Comment: @Emilien I made some tests, but I can't get it works, did you know how the compareWIth function works? The API it's not very clear about that